# RealmSwift: iOS Application crashes due to assertion failure on REALM_ASSERT_3(m_advancer_sg->get_transact_stage(), ==, SharedGroup::transact_Reading)

Tags: ios, swift, realm

**RealmSwift:** Sometimes, iOS Application crashes due to assertion failure on `REALM_ASSERT_3(m_advancer_sg->get_transact_stage(), ==, SharedGroup::transact_Reading)`

What can be the possible case of this **REALM_ASSERT_3** failure?

Sometimes, `m_advancer_sg->get_transact_stage()` is returning `transact_Ready` status.

This code block is executed in `clean_up_dead_notifiers()` method.

Comment: When you put a break point at the assertion what does the call stack look like? Also, is it triggered by user interaction?

Comment: That error could be caused by a number of things. Please perform some basic troubleshooting to identify the line of code that's causing the error. Then, update your question and include that code, which line caused the error and your observations about what may be causing it; a var is nil? divide by zero? Please take a moment and review [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: @Rob clean_up_dead_notifiers() is called in different thread. I think it is triggered when we are deleting objects from Realm

Comment: @Jay clean_up_dead_notifiers() is called in different thread. I think it is triggered when we are deleting objects from Realm